# How to select and move UIimageViews by tag?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, tags, uiimageview

i looking any methods how is possible touch at image and change your position. But same things a need for 20 images on screen. So i generate 20 UIimageViews with different tag. But i still don't know how select these UIimageViews by tag.

there is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    imageView = (UIImageView *)[imageView viewWithTag:imageView.tag] ; 
    NSLog(@"%d",imageView.tag);
    imageView.center = location;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    imageView.tag = arc4random() % 19;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageView = nil;

    for (int i; i<19; i++) {

        int randX = arc4random() % 240;
        int randY = arc4random() % 368;

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_1.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(randX, randY, 80, 92);
        imageView.tag = i;

        //NSLog(@"%d",imageView.tag);

        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    } 
}
```

thank you for reading

Comment: What is the problem with `viewWithTag`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of your tags, something like this:

```
#define TAG_VIEW1 1
#define TAG_VIEW2 2
```

You can easily do:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:TAG_VIEW1];
```

And that method will give you back the view of that tag.